# Android Broadcast Sending app's package name

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am aware of how `BroadcastReceiver` feature/functionality works in Android and I've implemented multiple actions that my app will either receive or send.

However, whenever one of my applications receives a broadcast I want to know which application sent that broadcast.

**Example (I have three applications):**
`Application A`  and `Application B` are allowed to send a broadcast to `Application C`.

When `Application C` receives the broadcast, I want to know which application sent this broadcast, either `Application A` or `Application B`?

Note: I am aware that I can add a `extra` in the `Intent` and send the package name however I am looking for a field that is "auto-generated".  I do not want to do the following each time:

```
intent.putExtra("package_name", getPackageName());
```

Reason, you ask?  Above is just an example. There could be more than two applications sending broadcasts and I don't want them to send package name in the `Intent` each time.

I also noticed there is `getPackage()` method for `Intent`, however that always returns `null`.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    switch (action) {
        case MY_GLOBAL_ACTION:
            // this is where I want the package name of the application that sent the broadcast
            intent.getPackage(); // this is always null
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know which application sent this broadcast, either Application A or Application B?

Add it as an extra.

> I am looking for a field that is "auto-generated".

There is none. By default, an `Intent` does not contain information about the app that created the `Intent`, any more than a `HashMap` does.

> I also noticed there is getPackage() method for Intent, however that always returns null.

Presumably, that is because you are not calling `setPackage()`. And, since that package does not identify the sender, it will not help you.